# How to plot false positive group separately with plot_roc_components with decision curve analysis in R?

Tags: r, analysis, curve, roc

I performed decision curve analysis based on a model that was predicting benign pathology with rmda package in R. Here is my code below.

```
`Model<-Outcome~Predictor1+Predictor2+Predictor3+Predictor4
 DC<-decision_curve(Model,data = M2,
                       study.design = "cohort",
                       policy = "opt-in", bootstraps = 1000)
 plot_decision_curve(DC,legend.position = "none",ylim=c(-1,1),
                               confidence.intervals =   FALSE)
 plot_roc_components(DC,confidence.intervals = FALSE,
                col = c("red", "blue"))`
```

With the plot_roc_components function, a plot that showed true and false-positive rates at each threshold was created (Fig1)

[a plot including true and false-positive rates at each thresold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txfwn.png)

Since output in the model has to be binary, I couldn't plot the false positives separately. I added an example of the graphic I want to do below ( Fig2). In this plot, TRUE positive: Benign Pathology and FALSE positive 1,2, and 3: good, mild, and bad cancer pathology. With plot_roc_component function, the false-positive line represents good, mild, and bad cancer pathology as one single group.

Which function or package should I use to plot like that? I hope I clearly stated my problem. Sorry for the bad English.

[Plot including shows false positive lines seperately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky1UK.png)